# How to install Open Gapps on Android Cuttlefish

Tags: adb, google-play-services, virtualization

I wanted to install Open Gapps (google play services) on cuttlefish virtual device (CVD). I tried using adb but flash archive is not present in the AVD image. Any idea how to install Open Gapps on CVD?

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/cuttlefish-use